# how to change "" in json to python

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, dictionary

i have a json data like this:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "mainEntityOfPage":{
        "@type":"WebPage",
        "@id":"https://cafef.vn/cuu-ceo-fpt-nguyen-thanh-nam-cac-chuyen-gia-smart-city-sao-khong-phat-ro-len-vi-co-co-hoi-giai-bai-toan-nuoc-song-da-20191108064344921.chn"
    },
    "headline": "Cựu CEO FPT Nguyễn Thành Nam bật mí về tổ chức "từ thiện cho người sắp giàu"",
```

but in the headline has "" which not allowed in python , so when i import json and get this data , i have an error

```
JSONDecodeError at /scrape/
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 9 column 70 (char 404)
```

how can i change "" in json data to python ??

Comment: What you have is not JSON data. Unescaped quotation marks are not allowed within JSON strings. Where does this data come from?

Comment: If this is supposed to be JSON, it's broken and needs to be fixed at the source. You can *try* to repair it, but there's no guarantee it's possible to unambiguously fix that.

Comment: Your json data is invalid. Like python, you should escape for `"` in JSON, too.

Comment: i not paste the rest of json data because i just want to ask for the "" in that data , sorry for your missunderstanding

Answer (score -1):

This json data is incomplete, but enough to see problem which is the double quote.

referring to this document:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm

you can add double quote by replacing with \"

example: I just take from your string,

"headline": "Cựu CEO FPT Nguyễn Thành Nam bật mí về tổ chức \"từ thiện cho người sắp giàu\""

Comment: Now, how to do this programmatically…?

Comment: how can you replace " to \" if you have " at the start and the end of string ?

Comment: @deceze sarcasm? Seriously, you would have to write a parser for "broken strings" or "broken JSON" which is almost certainly syntactically ambiguous because of the breakage. A heuristic is possible, a guaranteed fix that will always work is not! Is the data source paid for? A human fix is to get your boss to apply leverage to whoever is sending you junk that claims to be JSON, but isn't. Escalate or complain in a public forum if necessary.